# From printing a list how can I remove brackets, quotes and insert "and" before each last name

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, split

This code gives me the output: `The names found are: ['Alba', 'Dawson', 'Oliver']`

I would need to remove the brackets and quotes, and always print "and" before the last name (the number of names can be variable and for example I could have 3,4,5,6 names), so I would need this output:

```
The names found are: Alba, Dawson and Oliver
```

Code

```
name = "Alba, Dawson, Oliver"

names = name.split(', ')

print("The names found are: ", names)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use an array instead. `names = name.split(', ')`. Then just access by array index.

Comment: Right.  ANY TIME you find yourself creating variables like `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` etc., you need to replace that with a list.

Comment: @Nick Maybe that's not what I'm looking for, because I need to create new variables for each extracted name

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 Why do you want separate variable names for each variable? It will make your code incredibly complicated compared to just using a list. Please add detail to your question that demonstrates the need for it.

Comment: @Nick You are right. I have edited my question. Could you help me with an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've split the list into individual names, you can rejoin it with `,`  or `and` dependent on the length of the list:

```py
name = "Alba, Dawson, Oliver"
names = name.split(', ')
print("The names found are: ", end = '')
if len(names) == 1:
    print(names[0])
else:
    print(', '.join(names[:len(names)-1]), 'and', names[-1])
```

Output:

```
The names found are: Alba, Dawson and Oliver
```

Comment: Perfect. It was what I was looking for. I have tried to insert other names to the list and the last one is always printed with and. A curiosity please: could you explain the "else" part of the condition? (', '.join(names combine the names in the list with commas, and then what? What does names [: len (names) -1]) mean and what does names [-1] mean? Why -1? Thanks

Comment: The reason we have an `if` is just to deal with the special case of 1 name, so the first part does that (just prints the first element in the list), the second part (the `else` clause) prints first all the names from the first to the second to last (`name[:len(names)_1]`) joined with a `, `, then it prints `and` and finally the last name in the list `names[-1]`

Comment: Sure yes, understood. Thank you. You have been very kind. A little forgetfulness of mine, sorry. name will be the return of cursor.fetchall (), so it seems to me to have parentheses like name = "(Alba, Dawson, Oliver, Jim, Sarah)". With your code I will get The names found are: (Alba, Dawson, Oliver, Jim and Sarah). How can I remove the brackets? Thank you

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 you can [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) the brackets off: `names = name.strip('()').split(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

I see: you want to replace the final comma (`'` ) with `and`. This will do it.

```
splitted = [name.strip() for name in names.split(',')]
as_string = ', '.join(splitted[:-1]) + ' and ' + splitted[-1]
```

### Previous Answer

It sounds like you need to create a list, not assign to individual variables, and then index the list to get the names as variables.

```
name = "Alba, Dawson, Oliver"

names = name.split(', ')

print(names[0])
print(names[1])
print(names[2])

# but you can do this instead:
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(names[i])
```

Comment: Your answer helped me reflect and understand that I had the wrong way of thinking when writing the question code. Now I have edited the question. Could you help me? Thank you